# clipping an image objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, mask, crop

I created a Grid of Images.
The frames of those images are squares-shaped(CGRects).
Unfortunately the images fill-fits the square unproportionally.
But I would like to "crop" or "mask" the given image. Which means my frames will show only parts of an image but proportionally correct. I tried contentModes of UIImageView but no luck.

```
for(int index = 0; index < (_cols*_rows) ;index++)
{
    NSValue *value = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];    
    CGRect myrect = [value CGRectValue];
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    myImageView.frame = myrect;

    [self addSubview:myImageView];
    [myImageView release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure contentMode won't do what you want? If I understand you correctly, `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` will do exactly what you describe.

Comment: Hmm, check that the imageViews' `clipsToBounds` properties are set to YES.